# Problems encountered when connecting to Huawei Push

Tags: android, push, huawei-mobile-services

```
Cause: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Error: The inventory file cannot be found.
com.huawei.agconnect.agcp.AGCManifestProcess $ _process_closure1.doCall（AGCManifestProcess.groovy：47）
org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask $ ClosureTaskAction.execute（AbstractTask.java:739）
org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask $ ClosureTaskAction.execute（AbstractTask.java:712）org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter $ 1.run（ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131）
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor $ RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute（DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300）
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor $ RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute（DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292）
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute（DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174）
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run（DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90）
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run（DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31）
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction（ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120）
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions（ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99）
```

...31 more

The location of the project directory androidmanifest.xml is changed, but the specified manifest path exists in sourceSets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls upgrade the AGC plug-in.

Class path:`com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300`